# Footer do not stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am facng strange behaviour in IE 11. I have a page where data s pulled via AJAX, but footer is not moving down as size of that Section increases, i have made an image which will give you better idea,
Main issue is that my footer is not dynamic in IE,
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could post your HTML and CSS code for the page.

Comment: its long code thats why i didn't share, or only footer code ?

Comment: or somewhere we can test it

Comment: here is the URL: https://www.theglobalmuslim.com/index.php

Comment: @godfather And Numberc, is it enough for you to test it??

Comment: Add the following in the `<head>` of your document: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: Its already added, but still not working